# Login Failure: Pool is empty and connection creation failed

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth

when I tried to SSO using Shibboleth IDP, a login Error occured, when username and password was submitted as, Login Failure: Pool is empty and connection creation failed.

My error logs are as follows

```
==> /opt/shibboleth-idp/logs/idp-warn.log <==
at org.ldaptive.provider.jndi.JndiConnectionFactory.createInternal(JndiConnectionFactory.java:102)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:10389
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:216)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
2018-08-13 09:32:53,752 - WARN [org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool:600] - unable to create active connection
2018-08-13 09:32:53,753 - ERROR [org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool:197] - Could not service check out request
2018-08-13 09:32:53,754 - WARN [net.shibboleth.idp.authn.impl.ValidateUsernamePasswordAgainstLDAP:192] - Profile Action ValidateUsernamePasswordAgainstLDAP: Login by admin produced exception
org.ldaptive.pool.PoolExhaustedException: Pool is empty and connection creation failed
    at org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool.getConnection(BlockingConnectionPool.java:198)
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, answer for google.

Check `/opt/shibboleth-idp/conf/ldap.properties` if your domain/IP and port are correct.

In my case i missed out that the image `bitnami/openldap` uses port 1389 by default.